# Select * From table Where column Like statement c#

Tags: c#, mysql, select, oledb

I failed to get the correct result with this code in Form2:

```
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From udbTable Where Username Like '" + f1.textBox1.Text + "%'", conn);
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            label5.Text = reader["Username"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
```

I have 3 samples data in the table, but i'm always getting the same result which is the first entry of the database. Whenever i input the last entry or second entry in `the textbox1.Text`, i still getting the first entry.

`textbox1.Text` is from Form1, and i set it's property `Modification` to `Public`.
`label5.text` is the output.

Comment: What is the full query sent to the server after string concatenation? You should use parameterised queries to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @MartinSmith do you mean like the answer of Feras? i already tried that.

Comment: no that answer won't work. The percent needs to be added to the value before it is assigned to the parameter. You still haven't answered what is the query sent to the server though. You would see the results you describe if the text box value is blank just leaving the wild card.

Comment: @MartinSmith i understand what do you mean,  how am i suppose to do that? because from `f1.textBox1.text` is the input, users can give any possible input that is referring to the database. I don't have anymore idea to deal with this, i'm kinda new to c#

Comment: how did you add the sample data? if that was through a management application then you might need to `commit;` the changes so they become available

Answer (score 1):

try this fix

```
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection=conn;
command.CommandText = "Select * From udbTable Where Username Like ?";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username",OleDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value=f1.textBox1.Text;
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: already tried that, but it resulted me nothing. no changes happen.

Comment: check your connection string and make sure that you connected to the right database, then make sure of your table data

Comment: no doubt about the connection, i'm accessing the right database and with table

Comment: sorry for that, try this final try for me and give me a feedback @Rom

Comment: thanks for trying, but still the same result..i believe that all of your answer will output the same, you just declare the syntax in different ways